# Powershell - comparing arrays stored in hashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for some clean and efficient way to compare arrays stored in hashtable, without iterating over them ideally. Also without harcoding the `keys`

The `hashtable`:

```
Key   : somekey1
Value : {value1, value2, value3, value4}
Name  : somekey1

Key   : somekey2
Value : {value1, value2, value3}
Name  : somekey2
```

created with:

```
$hashtable = @{};

$hashtable[somekey1] = @();
$hashtable[somekey2] = @();
$hashtable[somekey3] = @();

ForEach ($key in $hashtable.keys)
{
$hashtable[$key] += value1;
}
```

I would like to call something like:

`Compare-Object $($hashtable.keys)[0] $($hashtable.keys)[1] -Property Value;`

and the expected output would be

```
value4
```

Is this possible? (asking as a PowerShell newbie)

Comment: A [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) like: `@{ somekey1 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'; somekey2 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' }` or actually a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)/object list? Please try to create a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: A hastable (i guess) - Iam declaring it as a hastable: `$hashtable = @{};` and then adding arrays like `$hashtable[somekey1] = @();` -> then filling with `$hashtable[somekey1] +1 value1;`

Comment: Thus: `$HashTable = @{ somekey1 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'; somekey2 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' }` ; `Compare-Object $HashTable.somekey1 $HashTable.somekey2`? if that doesn't answer the question, I suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73551991/edit) your question and add an *actual* example (not a description) of how you create the hashtable.

Comment: The point of this question is doing this without hardcoding key names. I've edited the question :)

Comment: [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables)s are unordered by nature. You need an *ordered* dictionary to be able to get the values by index (rather than key name): `$Ordered = [ordered]@{ somekey1 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'; somekey2 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' }` ; `Compare-Object $Ordered[0] $Ordered[1]`. Or do you want compare each key with any other key?

Comment: In your example you have 3 key-value entries in the hashtable. After comparing the arrays associated with `somekey1` and `somekey2`, what should happen then? Compare `somekey2` and `somekey3`? Should all possible key-combinations be compared? Or just the first 2?

Comment: @iRon Yes, but I imagine it is possible to add them with `foreach(key)` to the `$ordered`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen this is just an example, I am trying to make it as scalable as possible - so yes, Iam trying to compare all combination (in pairs ofc)

Comment: And what about the order of the arrays? e.g.:  `@{ somekey1 = 'value2', 'value1', 'value3''; somekey2 = 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' }`, are the entries considered equal here?

Comment: @iRon yes, I would consider these examples as equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each array only contains unique values, you can use [the `[HashSet[string]]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) to calculate the difference between two sets of strings:

```
# Define hashtable
$hashtable = @{
  somekey1 = @('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4')
  somekey2 = @('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
  somekey3 = @()
}

# Copy key collection
$keys = @($hashtable.psbase.Keys)

# Nested loops to compare each unique key pair
for($i = 0; $i -lt $keys.Count - 1; $i++){
  for($j = $i + 1; $j -lt $keys.Count; $j++){
    # Pick next two keys to compare
    $k1,$k2 = $keys[$i,$j]

    # Calculate symmetric difference of associated arrays
    $delta = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new([string[]]$hashtable[$k1])
    $delta.SymmetricExceptWith([string[]]@($hashtable[$k2]))

    # Output comparison results
    [pscustomobject]@{
        RefKey = $k1
        DiffKey = $k2
        Delta = $delta
    }
  }
}
```

`HashSet.SymmetricExceptWith` will calculate the symmetric difference between the two sets (the strings that are in one but not both), giving an output for the sample values like this:

```
RefKey   DiffKey  Delta
------   -------  -----
somekey1 somekey3 {value1, value2, value3, value4}
somekey1 somekey2 {value4}
somekey3 somekey2 {value1, value2, value3}
```